# Configure memory usage in sub-process created by java

Tags: java

I have an java application running on windows, which calls Runtime.exec("..*.exe") to start up a new sub-process for certain tasks.

Now I am wondering how can I configure the memory usage for this sub-process to be executed. should I just simply increase the memory usage of Java application or is there any sophisticated way?

Comment: What do you mean by "configure the memory usage"?

Comment: The memory used by that sub-process is pretty much managed by itself independently of your Java VM. So unless that .exe file has some arguments or configuration files that can influence it you'll just have to "trust it" to do its thing.

Comment: @Thomas I want to set how much memory could this sub-process use when I ran it

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks for your explanation. it makes sense to me now.

Comment: If you run a java sub-process , you can add -Xmx<Value> in the command, otherwise you can't set. Only the operating system allocate & manage the memory for the sub-process